# growth rate of $f(x)= x^{1/7}$

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity

Could anyone explain to me, please, what the growth rate of the function $f(x)= x^C$ is? ($C$ is a constant less than $1$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of time complexity.

It is  [fractional power time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity). It is also sublinear time.